# Not able to load my view controller after completed ~10 min in background

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, background, backgroundworker, background-process

I am putting my app in background for ~10 min (using `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler`) after Home Button pressed. At the end of 10 min I am setting a local notification to launch my app again to same view controller.

But when I interact with local notification I am not able to come on same view controller.
It's called `applicationWillEnterForeground` and then `didReceiveLocalNotification`. In `didReceiveLocalNotification` I am setting my view controller but no success.

**EDIT**

code in `didReceiveLocalNotification`

```
NF1AbcController *aBC = [[NF1AbcController alloc]init]; 
[self.navigationManager.defaultNavigationController pushViewController:aBC animated:YES];
```

Comment: can you post the code in 'didRevieveLocalNotification'  ?

Comment: @Sachin Please edit your own post with the changes next time, rather than to post it as a comment.

Comment: Thanks Hasturkun for updating my code.

Answer (score 0):

you have to make sure that your aBC view controller is not nill, also check that defaultNavigationController is not nil.

the appropriate way to do such thing is send a notification of type [NSNotifcation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000218-920)  inside the applicationDidRevieveLocalNotification method

also you will have to register the last view controller that was visible before the app entered the background ,when your view controller receives the notification is pushes your desired view controller

more on this in [apple Notification Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043-SW1)